# Android add margin for status bar, overlapping

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-viewpager

Currently I am designing a viewpager, the problem is as you can see in the image:

[image: Overlapping]

layout overlaps the statusbar. When I added the `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` to the styles.xml status bar becomes white, No overlap.

What I want to do is to make status bar in the same color with the main layout's color. I can set it like:

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);  
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#your color"));
```

but I don't want to do any operation in the swipe of the viewpager. It lags and also doesn't set the colors truely. What I think is maybe I can give marginTop(StatusBar Height) to the MainLayout.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Setting the statusbar color on application startup and padding the ViewPager from it so that they both have view space but don't overlap is an option for your case?

Comment: the background colors of the pages of the viewpager are different thats why I cannot use a single color. @AndreaCioccarelli

Comment: Ok I see; then I believe your best chance may be finding a way to set the color of the statusBar to transparent, so that it reflects the color of the underneath viewPager, and to set a top margin on the viewPager with a height equal to the status bar.